# Unable to plot the pdf

Tags: r, pdf, matrix, normal-distribution

I am unable to plot the pdf because the matrix that contains the values holding the probabilities is not functioning as I would want it to. Below is the code that I have written, please let me know where  am going wrong.

```
mu=c(1,-1)
covar=matrix(c(1,-1.6,-1.6,4),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
pdff= function(z){
pdf= ((exp(-t(z-mu)%*% solve(covar) %*% (z-mu))/2)/(6.283* sqrt(det(covar))))
return(pdf)
}


x=seq(3,5,length=50)
y=seq(2,4,length=50)
prob=matrix(NA, 50, 50)
for(i in x){
  for(j in y){

    prob[i,j]= as.vector(pdff(c(i,j)))
  }
}
```

prob matrix here is not getting filled up with probabilities. There are a lot of values that are still NA.

I need a solution  that helps in finding the prob matrix with all the values filled.

Comment: You need to iterate over `i in seq_along(x)` and similarly for y and use `as.vector(pdff(c(x[i], y[j])))` instead

Comment: alternatively you could do `outer(x, y, Vectorize(function(x, y) pdff(c(x, y))))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, got the prob matrix now. @rawr.